# synchronize two devices via android bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am pretty much new (read dummie) in Android. I am wondering what kind of information about my device could be sent over bluetooth at the time of device discovery?

Thanks ;)

Comment: you can not send any information unless you connect to other bluetooth device. Please elaborate your question if this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Hello @7383, thanks for your reply. Is it possible to automatically establish connection between devices? For example; device A and device B automatically discover each other and automatically connect and share some information? (lets say 1 picture for the sake of example)